# configuring external git diff tool for webstorm

Tags: git

I'm trying to configure `webstorm` to be external diff tool. Webstorm accepts two parameters which should be paths to comparable files, so if I run the following:

```
webstorm diff E/repo/file1.txt E/repo/file2.txt
```

Everything works fine. Now I try to put the configuration into config:

```
[diff]
    external = webstorm diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

I've tried to echo `$LOCAL` and `$REMOTE` params and they seem to contain full path to temporary files created by git, so everything should be working OK, but when I run

```
git diff master feature
```

the webstorm is launching but then I get the following message `external diff died, stopping at file.txt.` What am I doing wrong?

I've also found couple of other solutions:
[the first one](https://gist.github.com/jvandyke/4355099) suggests the following:

```
diff $(cd $(dirname $LOCAL) && pwd)/$(basename $LOCAL) $(cd $(dirname $REMOTE) && pwd)/$(basename $REMOTE)
```

But I get the following output:

```
dirname: too few arguments
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
basename: too few arguments
Try `basename --help' for more information.
dirname: too few arguments
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
basename: too few arguments
Try `basename --help' for more information.
```

And webstorm also exits without comparison. What does this configuration try to do?

```
$(cd $(dirname $LOCAL) && pwd)/$(basename $LOCAL)
```

The next solution is from [git manual](http://git-scm.com/book/ca/v1/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration):
It suggests that I create wrapper script:

> The diff wrapper checks to make sure seven arguments are provided and
>   passes two of them to your merge script. By default, Git passes the
>   following arguments to the diff program:

```
path old-file old-hex old-mode new-file new-hex new-mode
```

> Because you only want the old-file and new-file arguments, you use the wrapper
>   script to pass the ones you need.

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/extDiff 
#!/bin/sh
[ $# -eq 7 ] && /usr/local/bin/extMerge "$2" "$5"
```

I haven't tested this one, but I will after I understand why the previous two do not work.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jvandyke/4355099

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that, I've mentioned it in my question

Comment: For the hoops you're going through, why not just use something like Kdiff? It basically works out of the box and you don't need to worry about writing a wrapper.

Comment: @acanby, because I like webstorm

Comment: @Maximus fair enough, I just figured it might be a path of less resistance if you hadn't thought/didn't know about other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to my own questions in the original question:

> I try to put the configuration into config ...and it fails:

```
[diff]
    external = webstorm diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

`diff.external` **only accepts a name of a program to launch**. It launches this program and passes there 7 arguments. There are no `$LOCAL` or `$REMOTE` variables in the context of `diff.external` configuration settings. That's why it fails.

> The next solution is from git manual: It suggests that I create
>   wrapper script

Since `diff.external` doesn't accept anything more than just a program name, we need to find a way to filter out those 7 parameters and take only two required by webstorm. That's why we need that wrapper script to filter out those params and launch webstorm with only two.

So the configuration I use now is this:

```
[diff]
    tool = webstorm
[difftool]  
    prompt = false
[difftool "webstorm"]
    cmd = webstorm diff $PWD/$REMOTE $LOCAL
    trustExitCode = false
```

`difftool` in its `cmd` block specifies what command to run when you execute `git difftool -t "webstorm"` from command line. So it will run `webstorm diff $PWD/$REMOTE $LOCAL`. Notice that `$REMOTE` and `$LOCAL` variables are available to be used inside `difftool.cmd` block. In my case `$REMOTE` variable holds a path to a file relative to the current directory, i.e. simply `file1.txt`, while `$LOCAL` has full path, i.e. `E:/temp/file1.txt` (temp file created by git for comparison). Since webstorm requires full path, I add `$PWD` variable which has path to the current directory and combining it with `$REMOTE` I get the full path: `$PWD/$REMOTE` -`E:/myrepo/file.txt`. And the last thing, I used `-t` option above for the `gitdiff` to explicitly specify configuration of the diff tool to use. If you want `git` to use some default `difftool` configuration specify it in the `diff.tool` config variable (how it's done in my case).

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration, you wrote the word diff and it seems redundant. Try instead:

```
external = webstorm $LOCAL $GLOBAL
```

Comment: It needs to be there, edited the gist in my answer. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28644655/2545680), I've figured that out, you may find it useful